R Markdown Data Not Found
Plot1 When trying to knit my R markdown to HTML I keep running into an error message, "Error: ! object 'Plot1' not found Backtrace 1. base::plot(Plot1)." The chunks in the source window will run and render the plots but will not knit.
I tried to upload the data (completejourney) to the R markdown file so the file could source the data, but I had no luck. I think the issue lies somewhere there. I found online that the Global Environment does not recognize the data points in an R markdown. The code is below.
products %>%
inner_join(transactions, by = "product_id") %>%
filter(str_detect(product_category, regex("ICE CREAM", ignore_case = TRUE))) %>%
group_by(month = month(transaction_timestamp, label = TRUE)) %>%
summarize(total_sales = sum(sales_value)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = month, y = total_sales,color = month, fill = month)) +
geom_col() +
scale_x_discrete("Month") +
scale_y_continuous("Ice Cream Sales", label = scales::dollar) +
ggtitle(label = "Ice Cream Sales per Month", subtitle = "July has the most ice cream sales")

I am a beginner using R so any help would be greatly appreciated!

" the Global Environment does not recognize the data points in an R markdown".  That's correct and is most likely the source of your problem.  You need to create products in your markdown file, even if it exists in the global environment.  Without a reproducible example, it's not really possible to be more specific.

Welcome to SO! This question is similar to: Knit error. Object not found. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
